# después de aplicar formulario seguir en la misma pagina

Tags: php, formularios

me gustaría saber si existe alguna manera de por ejemplo responder un formulario y que ya aplicado su php o la manera que este lanzando la info siga en la misma pagina. no se si me explique mucho pero saben que tengo una pagina donde una parte de ella es un formulario que inserta en una DB pero me gustaria seguir en la misma pagina ya mencionada, claro que inserte en la DB pero que no me mueva o me mande al archivo en el cual estoy mandando la info ( php )

espero haberme explicado bien y espero que me puedan ayudar

PD ya intente usar include, header Location etc pero no se si haya mas formas de hacer esto

Comment: ¿El header location no te ha funcionado? ¿Podrías dar un ejemplo del código que estás usando actualmente? Con el fin de entender mejor a tu pregunta

Answer (score 1):

Esto se puede hacer creando un formulario donde la acción sea **#**.

En la misma página debe haber un **IF** que gestione la llegada o no de datos del formulario. Pones un **INPUT** oculto para controlar la llegada de formularios y los valores de forma normal.

Mira este ejemplo:

```
    <?php
      if(isset($_POST['insert'])) {
      // Aquí recibes los valores del formulario y le das el tratamiento necesario.

// Aquí podría ir el insert con la gestión de los datos por ejemplo...
// include('mi_php_con_el_inserta_BBDD.php');

      echo "<br />Estoy en la misma página y me ha llegado el valor: ".$_POST['value'];

      } else {
        echo "<br / />Aún no he recibido ningún valor.";
      }

     ?>

    <hr />
     <form method="post" action="#">
       <input name="insert" type="hidden"  />
       <input value="" name="value" id="value" type="text"  />
       <input type="submit" value="enviar" />
     </form>
```

---

**Utilizando AJAX**

Esto realmente refresca la página. Si queres que realmente no refresque la página, entonces debes utilizar AJAX que lo hace de forma asincrónica.  *Ajax con JQuery.*

En ese caso se crean dos archivos uno donde esta el JS y el HTML y otro con el php para gestionar los valores...

Archivo **formulario.php**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#enviar').on('click', function(){
var variable = $("#value").val();
console.log($(this).val());
$.ajax({
                url: "formulario_2.php",
                type: "POST",
                async: true,
                data: {
                  variable : variable} ,
                      success: function(result) {
                         $('#resultado').html(result);

                      },
                      error: function(result) {
                          $('#resultado').html('Error:'+JSON.stringify(result));
                      }
              });

})
});
</script>

<hr />

   <input name="insert" type="hidden"  />
   <input value="" name="value" id="value" type="text"  />
   <input type="submit" value="enviar" id="enviar"/>


<div id="resultado">
  Resultado de la variable= 0
</div>
```

Archivo **formulario_2.php**

```
<?php

echo "Actualizas la Base de datos con el valor de tu variable que és ...".$_POST['variable'];
 ?>
```

Comment: muchas gracias pero antes lo he probado pero al momento de tratar de llamar a mi php que inserta en la DB me dice que esta indefinida la variable

Comment: $b=$_POST['value'] ;

Comment: supongo que no "detecta" el input del formulario donde esta todo el codigo que tu me muestras :(

Comment: Dónde te dice que esta indefinida la variable? en Otra página php? No entiendo donde no detecta el `$_POST['value']`. Cómo llamas al php para insertar en tu BBDD? Con un `include`? Comentó la respuesta para que veas donde va el `insert`.